# jQuery insert after the last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add elements after the last one.
My current code

```
<div class="find"><div id="FirstElement"> /*First element loaded first */ </div><div>

$('#AddNextElement' + id).click(function (e) {
   $('<div id="NextElement' + id +'">' + /*Add after the last element*/ + '</div>').insertAfter($("#FirstElement"));
}
```

Current it adds only it after the first element:

> 1
>   4
>   3
>   2

I want it to add after the last element every time:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4

I've followed these links and I didn't find what I'm looking for:

[jQuery insertAfter last item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420281/jquery-insertafter-last-item)

[insertAfter specific element based on ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161678/insertafter-specific-element-based-on-id)

[jQuery: Add element after another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244605/jquery-add-element-after-another-element)

Thank you in advance!.

**How I fixed it:**

```
$('#AddNextElement' + id).click(function (e) {
   $('<div id="NextElement"' + id +'>' + /*Add after the last element*/ + '</div>').insertAfter($("#FirstElement").parent().find('.Finder').last());
}
```

*I found the .parent().find('.find').last(); then insert after the last*

Comment: Why can't you simply use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)?

Comment: `.append()` will make your work done

Comment: `"NextElement"' + id +'` this code return `"NextElement"0` `"NextElement"1` ecc... I thnik this is better: `"NextElement' + id +'"` return `"NextElement0"` `"NextElement1"` ecc...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just you need [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) method

```
$('<div id="NextElement"' + id +'>' + /*Add after the last element*/ + '</div>')
.insertAfter($('[id^="NextElement"]').last());
```

Comment: I tried add .last() and I'm still getting the same outcome!

Comment: did you use [id^= ...?

Comment: You were right about the .last()... I need to get the parent then find the last.
Thank you

Comment: last() should be before insertAfter()

Answer (score 8):

How about adding a class to all elements? It will be easier to find the last:

```
$('.element-class:last').after('<div class="element-class" id="NextElement"' + id +'>' + /*Add after the last element*/ + '</div>');
```

This of course means that your First element must also have the class:

```
<div class="element-class" id="FirstElement"> /*First element loaded first */ </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the last element in the DOM, in your case it'll be 'NextElementxx' and then use 'after':

```
$('#NextElement2').after( ..new stuff.. );
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="FirstElement"> First element loaded first  </div>

<div id="AddNextElement">Click me</div>
```

JS:

```
var current = 0;
$('#AddNextElement').click(function (e) {
    var $el = (current == 0) ? $("#FirstElement") : $("#NextElement"+current);
    current++;
    $('<div id="NextElement' + current +'">Other element '+current+'</div>').insertAfter($el);
});
```

Try yourself on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4j51r7nv/)

Answer (score 0):

one way is to store the last element.

```
<div id="FirstElement"> /*First element loaded first */ </div>

var lastElement = $('#FirstElement');

$('#AddNextElement' + id).click(function (e) {
    var element = $('<div id="NextElement"' + id +'>' + /*Add after the last element*/ + '</div>'));
    element.insertAfter(lastElement);
    lastElement = element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code, it will add the new div after the last "NextElement" div

**JS Code:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#AddNextElementButton').on("click", function (e) {
        var id = $("[id^='NextElement']").length ? $("[id^='NextElement']").length+1 : 1;

        if($("[id^='NextElement']").length){
            $('<div id="NextElement'+ id +'">Add after the last element</div>').insertAfter($('[id^="NextElement"]').last());
        } else {
            $('<div id="NextElement'+ id +'">Add after the last element</div>').insertAfter($('#FirstElement'));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**hope this will make you understand well  GitHub:Omar-baksh **

```js
// code by GitHub: omar-baksh 
// jquery is required online !!


       /*
       //this scricp test if jquery loded 

       window.onload = function() {
           if (window.jQuery) {  
               // jQuery is loaded  
               alert("Yeah!");
           } else {
               // jQuery is not loaded
               alert("Doesn't Work");
           }
       }
       */

var gfather = document.getElementsByClassName('Gfather');
var father =  document.getElementsByClassName('father');
var son = document.getElementsByClassName('son');


function gf(argument) {
$(gfather).mouseenter(function(){
 for (let i = 0; i < father.length; i++) {
  father[i].style.display='block';
 };
// show father fun() body show  body last ...

});

$(father).mouseenter(function(){
 for (let i = 0; i < son.length; i++) {
  son[i].style.display='block';
 };
// son show  body last ...
});



 // gf body last ...
}

// show form setting bottun fun()

function add(){
  const x = document.getElementById("frm").style.display='block';
 alert('setting opened');
 
}

// form  add element fun()
var clslist=document.getElementsByClassName("list");
var inher =document.getElementById("level");
var num =document.getElementById("num").value;
var txt =document.getElementById("inp-text");
// var add-btn = document.getElementById("btn-secsuce");

/*
$("#inher").change(function () {
 alert(inher);
 document.getElementById("inp-text")="you selected"+ document.getElementById("level").value;
 // body...
});
*/
var clss ="";
var ii;
$( "#btn-secsuce" ).click(function () {    
//txt.value="class name "+inher.value;  
    if( String(inher.value) =="Grand father"){
      clss ="Gfather";
 jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 999),
    text:txt.value,
    "class": clss,
    title: clss+clss.length
}).appendTo(clslist);

 alert("add class "+inher.value+gfather.length);
}


else { // alert("class enhhert is roung you chose " +inher.value )
 
}


/// add father to g father

if( String(inher.value) =="father"){
 var txt2 = $("<div class="+"father"+"></div>").text(txt.value);
  $(father[num-1]).after(txt2);


}

else{
 


}


});
```

```css
.Gfather{
  width: 60px;
  height: auto;
border-left: 6px dashed  red;
border-bottom: 6px dashed  red;
  background-color: silver;
 top:0;
  display:block;
position:relative ;
margin-left:9px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.father{
  width: 60px;
    border-left: 6px dashed  red;
border-bottom: 6px dashed  red;
 bottom:0;
  padding-top:0px;
border-right-width: small;
left:66px;
   white-space: nowrap;
position:relative ;
background-color: #550088;
color:white;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>tree js</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./tree.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="list">
      <div class ="Gfather" onmouseover="gf();">
      grand father 1
      
      </div> 
         <div class ="father">
          father
               
          </div>
        
        

            <div class ="son">son
           </div>
    <div class ="son">son
           </div>
   
       
          </div>
          <!-- add element show setting btn -->

          <button id="add" onclick="add()" > add setting</button>

       <form id="frm">

                                                     <h6>1</h6>
           <select id="level">
               <option>Grand father</option>
               <option>father</option>
               <option>son</option>
               
           </select>

          
                                                      <h6>2</h6> 
           <select id="num">
               <option>1</option>
               <option>2</option>
               <option>3</option>
               <option>4</option>
               <option>5</option>
               <option>6</option>
               <option>7</option>
               <option>8</option>
               <option>9</option>
           </select>
           <br>
                                                       <h6>3</h6>
            <input id="inp-text" type="text">

                                                 <h5 >4</h5>
            <button type="button" id="btn-secsuce"  >Add The Element  </button>
       </form>
       <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="./tree.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Wall of poorly formatted code with description "*hope this will make you understand well*" is not likely to make someone understand well. Also if it's not your code, add link with reference to original code

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this:

```
jQuery('##AddNextElement').last().after();
```